# How can I prevent \maketitle to reset the page number dinamically

Tags: titles, page-numbering

In my Latex document the page number is reset when I call the `\maketitle` function. My document class is `\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 14pt]{extreport}`.

An example is illustrated here:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 14pt]{extreport}
\title{Page resetting title}
\author{J Smith}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
first page          
\newpage
second page
\newpage
third page  

    \maketitle     

\newpage
fifth page
\newpage
sixth page

\end{document}
```

I would like to prevent this, but I don't know where the page number will be eventually.

I could use `\setcounter{page}{}`, but I don't know how to pass a dynamic argument.

Could anybody please tell me how to either prevent `\maketitle` from resetting the counter, or restore the count dynamically myself?

Comment: the standard `\maketitle` in  for example `article` class does not reset the page counter, so you need to give more information, preferably a complete small document that shows the problem.

Comment: Sorry. I've added an example now.

Comment: I have quickly skimmed through the code of the class you use (_extreport_), and indeed the `titlepage` environment resets the page counter to one.  @DavidCarlisle: (!) The _article_ class does the same (I repeat, in the `titlepage` environment, not in `\maketitle`).

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti the difference is that `article` by default doesn't use `titlepage`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I hope you are not annoyed because of the “(!)”: a smiley  was implied.  You will understand, that, talking to D. Carlisle from the depths of my 208 reputation, I was almost ashamed of daring make such a remark…

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti not at all:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the `notitlepage` option

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 14pt,notitlepage]{extreport}
\title{Page resetting title}
\author{J Smith}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
first page          
\newpage
second page
\newpage
third page  

    \maketitle     

\newpage
fifth page
\newpage
sixth page

\end{document}
```

Comment: Won't this have any (potentially unwanted) side-effects?

Comment: No title page (of course!).  The title is printed atop the fourth page (in your example), which nonetheless is empty because of the `\newpage`; though, the vertical alignment is quite different.

Comment: @user2565010 the only affect of the `notitlepage` option is to define `\maketitle` so it doesn't throw a separate page and doesn't restart the page counter.

Comment: Great. Thank you for the informative and clear answer.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can think of is to patch the definition of the `titlepage` environment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\titlepage}
    {\setcounter{page}\@ne}
    {}
    {}{}
% Also:
\patchcmd{\endtitlepage}
    {\if@twoside\else\setcounter{page}\@ne\fi}
    {}
    {}{}
\makeatother

\title{Page resetting title}
\author{J Smith}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
first page          
\newpage
second page
\newpage
third page  

% \show\titlepage
% \show\endtitlepage
    \maketitle     

\newpage
fifth page
\newpage
sixth page

\end{document}
```

But it is much simpler to use `\setcounter` at the appropriate place, I guess…!